# Possible ComputeCPP SYCL bug reading nested buffers

Tags: c++, sycl

I am trying to access a data structure with multiple levels of indirection on the GPU. The example hierarchy that I have now is A contains B contains C. Each contains data. A contains a pointer to B, B contains a pointer to C. When a heap-allocated data structure containing accessors is deallocated, the SYCL implementation segfaults in the accessors' destructors. When BView is destroyed, the segfault occurs.

I am using the ComputeCPP implementation for Ubuntu. This seems like a bug in the runtime because the buffers associated with the accessors in `BView` are still valid at the time of BView's destruction. There are not any other errors thrown. I also tried leaking `BView` to bypass the error. However, since BView's accessors hold a reference to the buffers for B and C, a deadlock results. This further indicates that the buffers referenced by BView's accessors are valid. Is it a violation of the SYCL spec to heap-allocate accessors or buffers? Maybe this could be causing the issues, since `AView` deallocates without any problems.

```
#include "SYCL/sycl.hpp"
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct C {
    int m_cData;

    C() : m_cData(0) {}

    ~C() {
        std::cout << "C deallocating" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct B {
    int m_bData;
    std::shared_ptr<C> m_c;

    B() : m_bData(0), m_c(std::make_shared<C>()) {}

    ~B() {
        std::cout << "B deallocating" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct BBuff {
    cl::sycl::buffer<B> m_bBuff;
    cl::sycl::buffer<C> m_cBuff;

    BBuff(const std::shared_ptr<B>& b) : m_bBuff(b, cl::sycl::range<1>(1)),
                                  m_cBuff(b->m_c, cl::sycl::range<1>(1)) {}

    ~BBuff() {
        std::cout << "BBuff deallocating" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<cl::sycl::access::target target>
struct BView
{
    cl::sycl::accessor<B, 1, cl::sycl::access::mode::read_write, target,
            cl::sycl::access::placeholder::true_t> m_bDataAcc;
    cl::sycl::accessor<C, 1, cl::sycl::access::mode::read_write, target,
            cl::sycl::access::placeholder::true_t> m_cAcc;

    BView(const std::shared_ptr<BBuff>& bBuff) : m_bDataAcc(bBuff->m_bBuff), m_cAcc(bBuff->m_cBuff)
    {
    }

    void RequireForHandler(cl::sycl::handler& cgh) {
        cgh.require(m_bDataAcc);
        cgh.require(m_cAcc);
    }

    ~BView()
    {
        std::cout << "BView deallocating" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct A {
    int m_aData;
    std::shared_ptr<B> m_b;

    A() : m_aData(0), m_b(std::make_shared<B>()) {}

    ~A()
    {
        std::cout << "A deallocating" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<cl::sycl::access::target target>
struct ABuff {
    cl::sycl::buffer<A> m_aBuff;
    std::shared_ptr<BBuff> m_bBuff;

    std::shared_ptr<BView<target>> m_bViewBuffData;
    std::shared_ptr<cl::sycl::buffer<BView<target>>> m_bViewBuff;

    ABuff(const std::shared_ptr<A>& a): m_aBuff(a, cl::sycl::range<1>(1)),
        m_bBuff(std::make_shared<BBuff>(a->m_b)) {
        m_bViewBuffData = std::make_shared<BView<target>>(m_bBuff);
        m_bViewBuff = std::make_shared<cl::sycl::buffer<BView<target>>>(m_bViewBuffData, cl::sycl::range<1>(1));
    }

    ~ABuff()
    {
        std::cout << "ABuff deallocating" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<cl::sycl::access::target target>
struct AView {
    cl::sycl::accessor<BView<target>, 1, cl::sycl::access::mode::read_write, target,
            cl::sycl::access::placeholder::true_t> m_bAcc;
    cl::sycl::accessor<A, 1, cl::sycl::access::mode::read_write, target,
            cl::sycl::access::placeholder::true_t> m_aDataAcc;

    ABuff<target>* m_aBuff;
    AView(ABuff<target>* aBuff): m_bAcc(*aBuff->m_bViewBuff), m_aDataAcc(aBuff->m_aBuff),
                                                 m_aBuff(aBuff) {}

    void RequireForHandler(cl::sycl::handler& cgh) {
        m_aBuff->m_bViewBuffData->RequireForHandler(cgh);
        cgh.require(m_bAcc);
        cgh.require(m_aDataAcc);
    }
};

class init_first_block;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::shared_ptr<A> a = std::make_shared<A>();
    try
    {
        cl::sycl::queue workQueue;
        ABuff<cl::sycl::access::target::global_buffer> aGlobalBuff(a);
        AView<cl::sycl::access::target::global_buffer> aAccDevice(&aGlobalBuff);
        workQueue.submit([&aAccDevice](cl::sycl::handler &cgh) {
            aAccDevice.RequireForHandler(cgh);

            cgh.single_task<class init_first_block>([aAccDevice]() {
                aAccDevice.m_aDataAcc[0].m_aData = 1;
                aAccDevice.m_bAcc[0].m_bDataAcc[0].m_bData = 2;
                aAccDevice.m_bAcc[0].m_cAcc[0].m_cData = 3;
            });
        });

        workQueue.wait();
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        std::cout << "Failure running nested accessor test" << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "A data: " << a->m_aData << std::endl;
    std::cout << "B data: " << a->m_b->m_bData << std::endl;
    std::cout << "C data: " << a->m_b->m_c->m_cData << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

As mentioned above, there is a segfault when deallocating `m_cAcc` in `BView`. Here is the [stacktrace](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11DcndcSkSPmMArUPl-pP-gKH-MZBb3Jc/view?usp=sharing) From the looks of it, the entire memory of the shared_ptr in the accessor to the buffer being accessed (m_cBuff) is invalid (not the memory pointed to, the actual data in the shared_ptr including the count). How can this be? `BView` is not deallocated multiple times, copied, moved etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave a presentation about some experiments in this area long time ago that explains the problem of the different memory views between host and device https://github.com/keryell/ronan/blob/gh-pages/Talks/2016/2016-03-13-PPoPP-SYCL-triSYCL/2016-03-13-PPoPP-SYCL-triSYCL-expose.pdf

More interestingly, Intel has a recent proposal to solve this that you could look at/contribute to: https://github.com/intel/llvm/blob/sycl/sycl/doc/extensions/USM/USM.adoc

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the crash was that the accessors in BView are not valid. Writing to the data pointed to by them corrupted the internals of the accessor, leading to the crash on destruction. The same code works if BView is not located in a SYCL buffer but is instead allocated on the stack before the command group. Removing the write to m_cData prevents the crash but illustrates that the write to m_bData does not go through successfully. It seems like placing accessors inside of SYCL buffers which are then accessed on a device is not supported behavior at the moment.

Comment: SYCL 1.2.1 prevents creating indirection on the GPU which is the intended behavor. Even if this did work, performance would be sub-optimal on a GPU. 
While CPUs are designed for this behavior, GPU memory architectures are not. 
Instead you can use SYCL buffers, arrays and indices on a GPU architecture.